# what is the meaning of global key word in .ascx designer files

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I am having a web application created in asp.net. In that we are having designer files for my user controls. In that controls are defined like following.

```
protected global::Common.Controls.ETextBox txtDummy;
```

what is the meaning of global key word in above statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the [global](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx) namespace. It allows you to compile things like:

```
class System
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       global::System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

Note that the class is called `System` and without the `global` keyword this won't compile as it won't find any static property called `Console` in this class. This being said you should **never** name your class `System`.